# KnpSnappyBundle Save File To Server

Tags: php, symfony, pdf

I am missing something in the KnpSnappy Bundle docs. :( How do I save my pdf to the server using Symfony and KnpSnappy. I don't want my pdf to download to the browser. I want it to save to the server. Please help! Thanks so much.

```
 Server Path: $pdfFolder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/symfonydev/app/Resources/account_assets/'.$account_id.'/pdf/'; 

 return new Response(
        $this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutputFromHtml($content),
        200,
        array(
            'Content-Type'          => 'application/pdf',
            'Content-Disposition'   => 'attachment; filename="'.$pdfFolder.''.strtotime('now').'.pdf"'
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see from [documentation](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle/blob/master/README.markdown) you need to use another function:

```
$this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->generateFromHtml($content, $pdfFolder . time() . '.pdf';
```

As you can see I replaced your `strtotime('now')` by `time()`. It will be faster.

Answer (score 4):

This line generates the PDF...

```
$this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutputFromHtml($content)
```

So you could probably just use [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) to write the result of **getOutputFromHtml($content)** to the file system.